# Subdomains with CloudFlare

Tags: hosting, dns, cloudflare

I'm using [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com) in my website and it works perfectly. Problem is, I decided to host my static files like JavaScript, CSS, etc. in `static.example.com` and I don't know how to set up the subdomain.

I already tried adding a CNAME record (`static` is an alias of `example.com`) and it didn't work, and as a A record (`static` points to `IPAddress`) where `IPAddress` is the IP address that both `www` and `example.com` use.

I'm I doing something wrong? I've waited about an hour for any DNS propagation problems and still doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder if we have to add either a CNAME record or a A record or both!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have added the subdomain in your CloudFlare DNS settings (settings->DNS settings), then it should start propagating out after a few minutes or so. If you're still having issues with the subdomain, please contact [CloudFlare](http://support.cloudflare.com/) with the domain name so we can look at it.

Comment: Was it that you hadn't clicked on the greyed out cloud?

Comment: How long does the subdomain propagation take?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue until I realized I had to click on the greyed out cloud on that row to activate Cloudflare on the subdomain. This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

The instructions at the top of the page clearly say you have to do this, but I'm not one of those read the manual types for simple tasks. I guess what would have really got the point across was some sort of notice the very first time I added a subdomain on my account.

Once you've clicked the icon, then the activated proxy will be indicated like this:

[image: using proxy]

Oh well, hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: That caught me too. I think newly added entries should be enabled by default.

Comment: I don't think whether the cloud is grey or orange makes a difference on whether the domain is available or not. It just determines whether cloudflare does caching etc.